# Adding multiple xElements at once using LINQ to XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have below custom class:

```
Public Class Frame

#Region " Enumerations "

    Public Enum FrameResult
        Success
        Failed
    End Enum

#End Region

#Region " Private Members "

    Private _timeStamp As Date
    Private _content As String
    Private _result As String

#End Region

#Region " Constructors "

    Sub New(ByVal timeStamp As Date, ByVal content As String, ByVal result As FrameResult)
        Me._timeStamp = timeStamp
        Me._content = content
        Me._result = result.ToString
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Properties "

    Public Property TimeStamp() As Date
        Get
            Return Me._timeStamp
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            Me._timeStamp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Content() As String
        Get
            Return Me._content
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._content = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property Result() As FrameResult
        Get
            Return DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(FrameResult), Me._result), FrameResult)
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As FrameResult)
            Me._result = value.ToString
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region


End Class
```

And I am trying to add multiple xElements at once to a XML document depending on if xml file exists or not:

```
Public Sub Add(ByVal frameData() as Frame) {

     if FileExists(xmlFile) then
        ' XML File exists

        xElem = XElement.Load(xmlFile)
        xElem.Add(frameData) --> not working

        ' Persist changes to file. Save to Disk
        xElem.Save(xmlFile)

     else
         ' File does not exist

        xDoc = New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", Nothing))
        xDoc.Root.Add(frameData)       

        sw = New StringWriter()
        xWrite = XmlWriter.Create(sw)

        xDoc.Save(xWrite)
        xWrite.Close()

        ' Persist changes to file. Save to Disk
        xDoc.Save(xmlFile)

     End If
```

But it does not work. I have tried to do:

```
       Dim _frame as Frame

       xDoc = New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", Nothing), _
        new XElement("Frames", _
        from _frame in frameData <--- not working, needs implements IQueryable
         select new XElement("TimeStamp", _frame.TimeStamp), _
            new XElement("Content", _frame.Content), _
            new XElement("Result", _frame.Result)))
```

but it does not work as frameData does not implements IQueryable and it seems so difficult... is there any other easy way?

My xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<frames>
    <frame>
        <timestamp>20/10/2016 07:30:05 AM</timestamp>
        <content>bla bla bla </content>
        <status>OK</status>
    </frame>
    <frame>
        <timestamp>20/10/2016 15:10:12 PM</timestamp>
        <content>bla bla bla </content>
        <status>FAIL</status>
    </frame>

    ... NEXT FRAMES ...

</frames>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [XML Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx), which allow you to [embed expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384752.aspx) to build up your XML from your objects.  It seems more natural to me than all those nested `New XElement`. e.g.

```vb
Dim frameData = {
    New Frame(Date.Now, "A", Frame.FrameResult.Success),
    New Frame(Date.Now, "B", Frame.FrameResult.Success),
    New Frame(Date.Now, "C", Frame.FrameResult.Failed),
    New Frame(Date.Now, "D", Frame.FrameResult.Success),
    New Frame(Date.Now, "E", Frame.FrameResult.Success),
    New Frame(Date.Now, "F", Frame.FrameResult.Success)
}

Dim xml As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><frames></frames>

Dim frames As IEnumerable(Of XElement) =
    From f In frameData
    Select <frame>
               <timestamp><%= f.TimeStamp %></timestamp>
               <content><%= f.Content %></content>
               <status><%= If(f.Result = Frame.FrameResult.Success, "OK", "FAIL") %></status>
           </frame>

xml.Root.Add(frames)
```

However, your comment about "not working, needs implements IQueryable" makes me wonder if you are missing a reference/import to something... or if I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Even using XML Literals is more readable, but the disadvantage is that it introduces dependencies with start/end tags and if in a future XML start/end tags change it requires to update all them. I have tried to replace them by constants to avoid this, but this does not work. Anyway, you are right, I was missing the import: "imports System.Linq". Your solution also works. Thanks very much for your great example ;)